Nginx: Accessing mounted files gives "Permission denied"
I'm using nginx to server static files. This works as expected but now I am trying to access files mounted on the filesystem.
So I have downloaded a zip file and used ratarmountto mount the zip file on to the filesystem. But when trying access the files I get a 404 error and when checking the error.log I see this:
2024/04/27 08:22:47 [crit] 111404#111404: *27 stat() "/var/www/html/forbes/rll/test.json" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 10.3.33.1, server: _, request: "HEAD /forbes/rll/test.json HTTP/1.1", host: "10.3.33.1"

This is the permissions for the directory
ubuntu@myserver:~/www/html/forbes/rll$ ll
total 1630
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root   root         0 Apr 19 13:41 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu       0 Apr 27 08:30 ../
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root   root   1665541 Apr 19 13:21 test.json*

Anyone have an idea on if you cannot use nginx on files mounted on the filesystem?
Or if I should change anything to make it work.

Check permissions for the parent directories.

All you have to do is either of following options:
Change ownership: Run sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/forbes/rll/ (assuming Nginx runs as www-data user and group). This will recursively change the ownership of the directory and its contents to the Nginx user.
OR
Change permissions: Run sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/forbes/rll/ to grant read and execute permissions to the Nginx user.
After making these changes, reload Nginx to apply the updates: sudo service nginx reload.
Just realised after chatting to asker:
You could update Nginx configuration: Add the user directive in your Nginx configuration file (usually nginx.conf) to run Nginx as the ubuntu user, which has appropriate permissions: user ubuntu;
Seeing as my previous answer didn’t work, this might!

ubuntu@myserver:~/www/html$ sudo chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/forbes/rll/ chmod: cannot access '/var/www/html/forbes/rll/': Permission denied
I cannot change the permissions :(

Why can’t you change the permissions? Did you say that already and I missed it or did you just test now? That’s annoying isn’t it!

I just tested it now. Yeah really annoying

Check my edit in my answer!

This works - thanks :)

No worries! Glad I could help!
